# c++ builder teeChart import timetag in text file

Tags: c++, import, runtime, vcl, teechart

I import a text file (with x and y coordinates) on `teeChart`. There are times like seconds that I want to do with the text to fill in. Adding the this time and x and y coordinates to the teechart when the program runs. I work on `rad studio c++ builder vcl` form app.

Example `0.3 second add (3,5)`

Example text file:

```
timetag   X   Y
0.3       10  5
```

---

[image]

ı cant use time. not all code only addcordinate button and openfile button

```
void __fastcall TForm1::AddCordBtnClick(TObject *Sender) {

        Series1->Clear();
        SeriesTextSource1->LoadFromStrings(Memo1->Lines);
}


void __fastcall TForm1::openFileBtnClick(TObject *Sender)
{

      if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
    {
        saveAsBtn->Enabled=true;
        spaceSep->Enabled=true;
        tabSep->Enabled=true;
        commaSep->Enabled=true;
        changeSep->Enabled=true;

        Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
        dosya_durumu=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: give code, not story

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/qaIbf

ı cant use time. not all code only addcordinate button and openfile button

void __fastcall TForm1::AddCordBtnClick(TObject *Sender) {
   
  Series1->Clear();
  SeriesTextSource1->LoadFromStrings(Memo1->Lines);
}


void __fastcall TForm1::openFileBtnClick(TObject *Sender)
{
 if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
 {
  saveAsBtn->Enabled=true;
  spaceSep->Enabled=true;
  tabSep->Enabled=true;
  commaSep->Enabled=true;
  changeSep->Enabled=true;

  Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
  dosya_durumu=true;
 }
}
@JacekCz

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do with the `timetag`. Please edit the question to clarify what do you want to achieve and what have you tried so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++builder read coordinate line to line tmemo add one by one tchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792652/cbuilder-read-coordinate-line-to-line-tmemo-add-one-by-one-tchart)

Answer (score 0):

[http://imgur.com/a/qaIbf](https://imgur.com/a/qaIbf)

ı cant use time. not all code only addcordinate button and openfile button

void __fastcall TForm1::AddCordBtnClick(TObject *Sender) {

```
    Series1->Clear();
    SeriesTextSource1->LoadFromStrings(Memo1->Lines);
```

}

void __fastcall TForm1::openFileBtnClick(TObject *Sender)
{

```
  if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
{
    saveAsBtn->Enabled=true;
    spaceSep->Enabled=true;
    tabSep->Enabled=true;
    commaSep->Enabled=true;
    changeSep->Enabled=true;

    Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
    dosya_durumu=true;
}
```

}
@JacekCz