# Add point (xy coordinates in text file) by time (in text file)

Tags: import, timer, c++builder, fstream, teechart

Times in memo2. xy coordinated in memo1.

There is an x and y coordinate in tmemo1. There is a timetag in tmemo2.

There are times like seconds that I want to do with the text to fill in. Adding the this time and x and y coordinates to the *teechart* when the program runs. I work on a RAD Studio C++ builder VCL Forms app.

Example: 0.3 second, add (3,5).

**Example text file:**

```
timetag       X       Y
0.3           10      5
```

**Error message:**

> [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(261): E2034 Cannot convert 'UnicodeString' to 'TStrings *'
>   [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(261): E2342 Type mismatch in parameter 'AStrings' (wanted 'TStrings *', got 'UnicodeString')

**Code:**

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for(int i=0; i<Memo2->Lines->Count; i++)
    {
       Timer1->Interval=(Memo2->Lines->Strings[i])*1000;
       String coord=Memo1->Lines->Strings[i];
       SeriesTextSource1->LoadFromStrings(coord);
       Timer1->Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very difficult to decipher what you are asking; There are a number of issues here; but the compiler's error message is fairly straight forward:  The `SeriesTextSource1->LoadFromStrings` wants a TStrings type parameter and you are trying to pass the variable `coord` which is of type `String`.....

Comment: First, what type is `SeriesTextSource1`?  It may have method similar to `LoadFromStrings` that takes a single `String` instead of a `TStrings`.  If not, then you will need to setup a temporary `TStrings` instance and load the one line into it and then past this temporary `TStrings` to `LoadFromStrings`. Second, why are you are changing the `Interval` of `Timer1` on **every** iteration of the loop?  I realize your test text file has only 1 line, but if this procedure was processing a file of multiple lines there would surely be no point to the manipulation of `Timer1` within the loop.

Comment: not one lines in text file this example like there are 192 lines in text file

Comment: Well, OK; Then my final question/comment/observation still remains: Why are you changing the `Timer1->Interval` on **every** iteration?  At the statement `Timer1->Enabled = true;` there will never be enough time for `Timer1` to expire and fire an event before it gets changed on the next iteration.  **And**, this is a *secondary* point to your original question.  Again, what is the type of `SeriesTextSource1`?  It may be helpful if you showed us a little more code (like declarations for the key variables).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++builder read coordinate line to line tmemo add one by one tchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792652/cbuilder-read-coordinate-line-to-line-tmemo-add-one-by-one-tchart)

Comment: @tahacanatak please do not post duplicate questions instead update your original one. Not sure which one was the first as both where created yesterday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ builder teeChart import timetag in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692247/c-builder-teechart-import-timetag-in-text-file)